# Display text representation of a date as a formula result

Tags: google-sheets, date-formatting

I get this date format from Zapier

```
2018-08-16T01:13:58
```

I use this formula to split and extract the first half of the split (the date).

```
=index(SPLIT("2018-08-16T01:13:58","T"),0,1)
```

Google Sheets displays the formula output as a number, e.g. **43328**

If I format this cell manually, using the menu *Format >> Number >> Date*, Google Sheets will display it as the formatted date, e.g. **16/08/2018**

If I use `DATEVALUE()` as such:

```
=datevalue(index(SPLIT("2018-08-16T01:13:58","T"),0,1))
```

then the cell displays **#VALUE!**

> Error `DATEVALUE` parameter '43328' cannot be parsed to date/time.

How can I write my formula such that it is displayed as formatted date, without having to format the formula's cell through the menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TEXT function:

=TEXT(43328,"dd-mm-yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

Date shows in google spreadsheet are formatted by google spreadsheet settings. If you want to change the datetime format of your sheet, you will have to change Locale setting to that of your need.

If you don't want to go over settings, you can set it manually by code.

First, you will need to put this formula `=SPLIT("2018-08-16T01:13:58","T") + ""` somewhere to get the date value. Here I assume you use cell "Z1"

Now, you will have to change the date format each time "Z1" changes it value. I use onEdit(e)

```
function onEdit(e) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
      if (range.getColumn() == 26 && range.getRow() == 1) { // if Z1 is modified
        var d = ss.getRange("Z1").getValue()
        var inputDate = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT+7", "dd/MM/yyyy")
        ss.getRange("B5").setValue(inputDate)
        }
      }
```

There you go. Each time Z1 change, which means the date value is inputted, the correct date + format will be reflected in B5.

Comment: This gives me a result of 2018-08-16 but when I try and use a datevalue I still get 43328, what I'm looking for is a date with DD/MM/YYYY

I used =datevalue(SPLIT("2018-08-16T01:13:58","T") + "")

Comment: Well, that is a google spreadsheet settings matter. No way to change date time format by formula. Although you can do it with script : upon edit the cell, change the date format of the result cell. Use onEdit(). I will edit my answer, add some more code for you.

Comment: The sheet settings is set to the UK, so the date formatting should be DD MM YYYY. Still doesn't work.

Comment: using =SPLIT("2018-08-16T01:13:58","T") + "" how do I get the second part after "T" the time that is?

Answer (score 0):

After much searching this seems to work for me.

```
=regexreplace(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT("2018-08-16T10:02:29","T") + "","-","/"), "^(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)$", "$3/$2/$1") & " " & regexreplace(RIGHT("2018-08-16T10:02:29", find("T","2018-08-16T10:02:29") -3), "^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$", "$1:$2:$3")
```

Outputs **16/08/2018 10:02:29**